# Как вычислить разницу между датами в UTC?

Tags: php, utc

Хочу найти разницу между двумя датами в днях.

```
$date1 = strtotime("2019-06-20 00:00:00");
$date2 = strtotime("2000-01-01 00:00:00");
$days = ($date1 - $date2)/60/60/24; //7110
```

У меня получается 7110 дней. Все хорошо, но в UTC должно получиться 7109 дней. Как найти разницу в UTC?

Вот в c# например у меня получается 7109

```
var expiration_date = DateTime.Parse("20.06.2019 00:00:00");

(int)(expiration_date.Value.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Разница между этими датами в UTC ровно 7110 дней 0 часов 0 минут 0 секунд. Откуда вы взяли 7109?

Comment: Разница "в UTC" ничем не отличается от просто разницы.

Comment: @Эникейщик внёс правки

Comment: @andreymal внёс правки

Comment: В c# у вас время для expiration_date не 00:00:00, а текущее. Получается дробный день, который отбрасывается при (int).

Comment: Ну и странно, что вы по какой-то причине считаете результат c# правильным, а результат php неправильным. Ведь все может быть совсем наоброт.

Comment: Ваш код на C# не эквивалентен коду на PHP. На PHP вы берёте даты в одном и том же часовом поясе, а на C# - в двух разных часовых поясах. Естественно будет разный результат

Comment: @andreymal в смысле в двух разных

Comment: @Radzhab expiration_date использует часовой пояс компьютера, который совершенно необязательно совпадает с UTC. Если у вас на компьютере московское время, то после преобразования в UTC получится 19 июня 21 час, потому что разница между Москвой и UTC три часа. И тут уже естественно получится разница 7109 дней и 21 час

Comment: @andreymal вот скрин https://pasteboard.co/Ijn5iTD.png

Comment: @Radzhab на скрине именно то, о чём я и сказал - 19 июня 21 час. Значит и в PHP тоже пишите 19 июня 21 час, если хотите получить 7109 дней

Comment: @andreymal нижний ответ получается корректный так?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых разница выводится правильно. Чтобы получить разницу 7109, в вашем случае не получится в днях, можно использовать такой вариант:

Тут вторая дата отличается на 1 секунду, и считает в днях верно

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2019-06-20 00:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2000-01-01 00:00:01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a дней'); // -7109 дней
```